# does WSS 3.0 search index document libraries?

Tags: search, wss, wss-3.0

I have a document library with a few files in it and I've noticed that doing a search for files in the document library (even the exact file name) does not seem to give any search results. The search does seem to provide results of terms within lists (such as Project Tasks) thought.

Does Sharepoint Services 3.0 index files within document libraries? I've gone into Advanced Settings of the document library -> Search and made sure the radio button is set to 'Yes' (it was 'Yes' by default).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, after doing a little digging around it turned out the Service Account and Content Access Account in SharePoint Central Administration > Operations > Services on Server > Windows SharePoint Services Search Service Settings were both set to the in-built user "Local System" which didn't have the permissions to fully index the site. What was odd was that it was indexing the lists but not the documents - I presume a different type of indexing operation is done on the two.

I created a new user on the server with the relevant permissions and assigned that to the Service and Content Access Account and within minutes I could see the Document Libraries within the search results.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is Yes.

The long answer will require some further reading as I can't remember how or where to set it up and of course there is always the chance you have it configured but it just isn't working.